# Why does wordpress and my site create a downloadable file instead of allowing me to login?

Tags: wp-admin

I have a wordpress site hosted by Blue Host (www.doseofdiscovery.com). I was deactivating and deleting a few plugins today and now I am not longer able to access wordpress or my site. When I navigate to the web address in a search bar, it downloads a file just called "download" instead. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing browser, depending on wich browser Chrome: On window: shift+ctrl+r, On mac: shift+cmd+5. The url: https://www.doseofdiscovery.com/ is working just fine with me. Also tried https://www.doseofdiscovery.com/wp-admin with no creation of a download-file.